# Updating Parse to UIAlertCotroller with Cocapods

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods, xcode7

After taking some time off working on IOS i have just updated to Xcode 7.1 Version 7.1.1 (7B1005).

After the update i had issues running a project using Parse frame works, so i ran pod install again to update everything. (pods output below)

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Bolts (1.2.2)
Using Parse (1.8.5)
Using ParseUI (1.1.6)
Using PercentEncoder (1.0.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total
pods installed.
```

This worked fine and now the project builds and runs again perfectly with one notable exception.

I am now getting warnings regarding the deprecation of UIAlertView in IOS9(i know this has been replaced with UIAlertCotroller). These warnings are pointing to the ParseUI framework files.

```
'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
```

All of the following fines receive the same warning.

```
PFUIAlertView.h
PFLogInViewController.m
PFQueryCollectionViewController.m
PFQueryTableViewController.m
PFUIAlertView.m
```

Is this happening because the Parse UI is out of date? Or have I missed something or done something wrong?

None of my code has any errors or warnings.

I have looked high and low and it seems no one else is having this issue.

Please help I am stuck and have no idea wear to look.

Comment: Have now updated to Xcode 7.2 and still issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the Parse-UI project is out of date. Looking at the header, it extends `UIAlertView`:

```
// PFUIAlertView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PFUIAlertView : UIAlertView

+ (void)showAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                         error:(NSError *)error;
+ (void)showAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                       message:(NSString *)message;
+ (void)showAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                       message:(NSString *)message
             cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle;
@end

// PFUIAlertView.m
+ (void)showAlertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                       message:(NSString *)message
             cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[self alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                 message:message
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
```

For what its worth, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/issues/172), but work on that seems to have stalled. Maybe bringing it up there will help get the update going.

You can find the full source [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/tree/master/ParseUI/Classes/Internal/Extensions).

Comment: Thats what i thought. Thank you. Am i right that if i replace the UIalertview code in the ParseUI files with UIAlertController like i have in my own code it should fix the problem until there is an update from Parse?

Comment: @joffd I don't think so. `UIAlertController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so it needs to be handled like any other view controller. Plus, setting up the buttons is very different. My advice is to avoid using the `PFUIAlertView` all together (if possible), and use `UIAlertController` directly. And honestly, [it is easier to work with](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/). Second, if you start editing the Parse files, those edits are lost on the next `pod update` or `pod install`.

Comment: @joffd You could look into [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) and replace the PFUIAlertView's implementation with your own. I can't help with that one though.